# Factorization and simplification, algebra.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please, there is a way to factor out this expression? I couldn't find a way.

$$\frac{2a^{2}+3ab+2b^{2}}{4ab^{2}+4a^{2}b}$$

Comment: Well, the bottom factors into $4ab(a+b)$.  Do any of these divide the numerator?  Why do you expect this to have a "nicer" expression?

Comment: Because i must calculate the roots of a function and these roots will be "a" and "b". Then I must find the answer, I thought it had an easier way to calculate this expression. I did what you did, but just to be sure, you know?! (Sorry if there are English mistakes, I speak Portuguese)

Comment: While not a factorization the expression $\frac{a+b}{2ab}-\frac{1}{4(a+b)}$ is equivalent (assuming denominator in original expression isn't zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. The denominator factors into $4ab(a+b)$. The numerator is not divisible by $4$, $a$, or $b$, and after using polynomial division, it becomes apparent that the numerator isn't divisible by $(a+b)$ either. When one attempts to divide $2a^2+3ab+2b^2$ by $a+b$, the answer is $2a+b$ with a remainder of $b^2$.